# psycopg.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "ON" with execute

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg3

I'm using psycopg3 and PostgreSQL 14. When I run a copy or exec function, and include a ON argument, it gives me the error `psycopg.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "ON"`

I have tried two different functions, both resulting in the same error.

```
 cur.execute("""
  CREATE TABLE temp_mls AS TABLE mls_properties WITH NO DATA
  ON COMMIT DROP
   """)
```

and

```
cur.copy("""COPY mls_properties (fips_code") FROM STDIN
            ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
                """)
```

Comment: I don't think `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` is valid in `COPY` - see [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-copy.html).

Comment: @snakecharmerb That's what I also thought, but have the exact same error on execute.

Comment: Because `ON..` is not valid syntax for the _PostgreSQL_ copy command.  Nothing to do with psycopg.

Comment: Good point, also seems ON is invalid for create table as well. Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

No "CONFLICT" word in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html.

Obviously, `ON COMMIT DROP` should warp in an **transaction**. However it only apply to temp table. Quote from [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtableas.html):

> ON COMMIT
> The behavior of temporary tables at the end of a transaction block can be controlled using ON COMMIT. The three options are:
> PRESERVE ROWS
> No special action is taken at the ends of transactions. This is the default behavior.
> DELETE ROWS
> All rows in the temporary table will be deleted at the end of each transaction block. Essentially, an automatic TRUNCATE is done at
> each commit.
> DROP
> The temporary table will be dropped at the end of the current transaction block.

So the following will work:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE temp TABLE temp_mls ON COMMIT DROP AS table test WITH NO DATA;
COMMIT;
```